# Visual Studio Nuget install 'app.config is in use'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I can't seem to install the nuget package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 18.3.0.0 in my C# class library.

Whenever I try to install it it throws the following error:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: An error occurred while applying transformation to 'App.config' in project 'MyClassLibrary' The process cannot access the file 'R:\DEV\MyClassLibrary\App.config' because it is being used by another process. ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'R:\DEV\MyClassLibrary\App.config' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at NuGet.ProjectManagement.FileSystemUtility.CreateFile(String fullPath)
```

When I delete the app.config before attempting to install the nuget it will recreate it during installation of the nuget, and this error perists. It refuses to install.

AFAIK there are no other processes running. After a reboot the same issue persists.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Pro. What can be the problem?

Comment: It's seems your project is not under solution directory, you can create a new project at default `C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\` to check if this issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow [workarounds in this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows) to figure out which is occupying the file.

Also Try:

1.Uninstall that package in current project

2.Tools=>Nuget Package Manager=>Package Manager Settings=>Clear All nuget caches

3.Navigate to Project directory, delete the bin and obj folders. Also delete the packages folder in Solution directory if it exists.

4.Then start VS as admin to install the package, I suggest you can install it by Nuget package manager UI.

Comment: I have tried these steps, except starting as admin. Since this is a work PC and it's a secure environment I don't have admin rights available to me. So solutions in the linked issue are also impossible since they require admin rights. However, since VS creates the file while installing the nuget I can be relatively certain there is no other program occupying it...

Comment: Hi, same issue persists if you create a new empty class library in new solution and consume that package?

Comment: yes it does. it seems to be Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework. However. after clicking install again for 4 times, it went through

Comment: @Bjorn Glad to know it now works, if you can locate the cause of the issue and the workaround of that one day, don't forget to add it as answer:)